# finding the radius of a circle that intersects a sphere

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm an openGL programmer, trying to construct a sphere in specific circumstances.

Imagine a sphere sliced up into numerous flat horizontal circles.

Given a position along the vertical (Y) axis of the sphere and the radius of the sphere, how do I get the radius of the circle that is on the (X,Z) plane that intersects the Y axis at that point?

Comment: It's not clear to me what circle you're looking for. Do you want the radius of the "flat horizontal circle" at height $y$ (the intersection of the plane parallel to the  $x$-$y$ plane at height $y$ with the sphere)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sphere of radius $R$ is the solution set of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$ in which $x, y,$ and $z$ all vary.  A slice of the sphere perpendicular to the $y$-axis has the same equation except that $y$ is a fixed number.  So we have $x^2 + z^2 = R^2 - y^2$.  With $y$ fixed, this is the equation of a circle with radius $\sqrt{R^2 - y^2}$.

Comment: that was it! I got stuck trying to play with sine and cosine, and never getting it. In all honesty, I figured it out myself an hour after I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe from your description it should be $\sqrt{R^2-y^2}$. This function is 0 at the top and bottom and $R$ right in the middle.